# Careers 2.0 isn't sending confirmation email after applying for a job

Tags: support, jobs, email-verification

Why doesn't Careers 2.0 send me a confirmation email after applying for a job?
Usually it sends one, but a couple of days ago I applied for some jobs and no confirmations were sent to me.

What if my applications weren't sent to the employer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report Chiron and I'm really sorry about this.  Our virus scanner server had an issue that was keeping your applications from being sent.  I've fixed the glitch and your applications have now been sent.  Again, my apologies.

Comment: Indeed, I got the email notifications now. Big thank you. Only my applications were problematic?

Comment: virus scanning is awesome.

Comment: Do you also send confirmation emails for users with no Careers profile? (see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242362/confirmation-email-for-application-without-profile)