# Confirmation email for application without profile

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, email-notification

I don't have a career profile ans I applied yesterday to a job on stackoverflowcareers by entering manually my contact information, covering letter and attaching my resume.

I did not receive a confirmation email that the application had been sent correctly, is that normal?

I don't have any message listed either in my profile.

Thanks

Comment: The company I apllied to just checked my LinkeIn account so I guess they received my application. But it would be best if I received a confirmation by email from career that the application was sent.

Comment: Regarding message in your profile, what do you mean? You said you don't have a  Careers profile.

Comment: When I am logged-in in career I can see on top right corner a button called messages that is empty. I don't have a profile in the way that I don't have enough reputation to have my resume on career, I need to apply on my own.

Comment: I don't get it... you can be logged in but you don't have a profile?

Answer (score 3):

You should get an email confirmation when you submit a job application. If you didn't receive one, please email support at careers@stackoverflow.com and we'll take a look into it.

Comment: OK I sent the email

Comment: Alex, can a user be logged in to Careers, but not have a profile? I'm confused by [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242362/confirmation-email-for-application-without-profile?noredirect=1#comment792482_242362), unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, anybody can create a login, but you need to be invited before you can create a profile.

Comment: Thanks, sounds bit weird but think I got it.

Comment: Thanks Shadow Wizard, that's exactly my situation